# Trying to run faac's bootstrap script but running into errors

Tags: linux, build, autotools, bootstrapping

I'm trying to install faac and am running into errors.  Here are the errors I get when trying to build it:

---

```
[root@test faac]# ./bootstrap  
configure.in:11: warning: underquoted definition of MY_DEFINE
run info '(automake)Extending aclocal'  
or see http://sources.redhat.com/automake/automake.html#Extending-aclocal  
aclocal:configure.in:17: warning: macro `AM_PROG_LIBTOOL' not found in library  
common/mp4v2/Makefile.am:5: Libtool library used but `LIBTOOL' is undefined  
common/mp4v2/Makefile.am:5:   
common/mp4v2/Makefile.am:5: The usual way to define `LIBTOOL' is to add `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL'  
common/mp4v2/Makefile.am:5: to `configure.in' and run `aclocal' and `autoconf' again.  
libfaac/Makefile.am:1: Libtool library used but `LIBTOOL' is undefined  
libfaac/Makefile.am:1:   
libfaac/Makefile.am:1: The usual way to define `LIBTOOL' is to add `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL'  
libfaac/Makefile.am:1: to `configure.in' and run `aclocal' and `autoconf' again.  
configure.in:17: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PROG_LIBTOOL  
If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.  
See the Autoconf documentation.
```

---

Does anyone know what this means?  I was unable to find anything about this so I figured I'd ask you guys.  Thank you for your help.

EDIT:
Here's my versions of linux, libtool, automake and autoconf:

```
[root@test faac]# libtool --version
ltmain.sh (GNU libtool) 2.2
Written by Gordon Matzigkeit <gord@gnu.ai.mit.edu>, 1996

Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
[root@test faac]# autoconf --version
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.59
Written by David J. MacKenzie and Akim Demaille.

Copyright (C) 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
[root@test faac]# automake --version
automake (GNU automake) 1.9.2
Written by Tom Tromey <tromey@redhat.com>.

Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
[root@test faac]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux WS release 4 (Nahant)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the first thing to check is that you have libtool installed.

Edit:

This is what I get on Ubuntu 8.04:

```
$ ./bootstrap 
configure.in:11: warning: underquoted definition of MY_DEFINE
configure.in:11:   run info '(automake)Extending aclocal'
configure.in:11:   or see http://sources.redhat.com/automake/automake.html#Extending-aclocal
configure.in:4: installing `./install-sh'
configure.in:4: installing `./missing'
common/mp4v2/Makefile.am: installing `./depcomp'

$ libtool --version
ltmain.sh (GNU libtool) 1.5.26 Debian 1.5.26-1ubuntu1 (1.1220.2.493 2008/02/01 16:58:18)

Copyright (C) 2008  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ autoconf --version
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.61
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software.  You may redistribute copies of it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David J. MacKenzie and Akim Demaille.

$ automake --version
automake (GNU automake) 1.10.1
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv2+: GNU GPL version 2 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Tom Tromey <tromey@redhat.com>
       and Alexandre Duret-Lutz <adl@gnu.org>.
```

Comment: I believe I do because I checked using the whereis command:
[root@test faac]# whereis libtool
libtool: /usr/bin/libtool /usr/local/bin/libtool
[root@test faac]# whereis libtoolize
libtoolize: /usr/bin/libtoolize /usr/local/bin/libtoolize

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is that automake/conf don't know about libtool.

You need to reinstall all of them. Either from all from source, or all from binary packages.
If installing from source, ensure they are all installed to the same location.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your automake doesn't know about your libtool for some reason. It looks like you've got two copies of libtool installed, which might be confusing it.

Maybe you should remove both copies, plus all automake, autoconf installs, and reinstall them (possibly from source?).

I guess the first step is to find out the locations of the active copies of the tools:

```
which libtool
which automake
which autoconf
```

Comment: i have a symlink from libtool in /usr/local/bin to usr/bin. here are the results of commands above: 
    [root@test ~]# which libtool 
    /usr/local/bin/libtool 
    [root@test ~]# which automake 
    /usr/bin/automake
    [root@test ~]# which autoconf 
    /usr/bin/autoconf

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like autoconf/automake cannot find `libtool.m4`, and therefore cannot resolve the macro `AM_PROG_LIBTOOL`.  Look for this file under your libtool installation and copy/link it under `/usr/share/aclocal/`.